# Retaining previous zoom value on a Map update in Google Maps API v2 for Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, zooming

I'm working on a map based application. What it does is receives data from servers for the latitude and longitude. It refreshes data every x seconds. It then moves a marker on the map to the new location(the changed one) that was received.

My problem is, while using the map, I don't want the zoom level to be reset for the marker. I want it to retain the zoom level that the user may have adjusted to while looking at the map.

I have a marker named bus defined as an instance variable:

```
  Marker bus = null;
```

Here is the code for my BroadCast Receiver that recieves an intent that the data has been refreshed.

```
    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        //public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

               if(bus!= null){
                   bus.remove();
               }

            bun = ((TabActivity)Tab2Fragment.this.getActivity()).getDataFromActivity();
            try{
            BusLocation = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(bun.getString("lat")),Double.parseDouble(bun.getString("long")));
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bus = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(BusLocation)
                    .title("Bus is Here")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

                // Move the camera instantly to the Bus Location with a zoom of 15.


map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BusLocation, 15), 1000, null);

        }
    };
```

Every time it updates, it re-zooms the level. How do I not rezoom the level?
I tried using newLatLng() instead of LatLngZoom, but then on initialization, it is zoomed extremely far away. And I won't have data avaiable to zoom  it in with relevance.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I think it is simple try to manage flag.

Comment: Yeah. Just did that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, its way too simple. I wasn't thinking. For what it's worth:

Have a boolean value

```
private boolean first = true;
```

Then in the update:

```
            if(first)
            {
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(BusLocation, 15), 1000, null);
                first = false;
            }
            else{
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(BusLocation), 1000, null);
            }
```

Comment: and what about BusLocation @Ra41P